# How can I load environment variables via command line when running a node.js app in cluster mode with PM2?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pm2, dotenv

When starting my application with node, I typically run:

```
node -r dotenv/config ./build/index.js
```

When using PM2 in fork mode I can start the application like so:

```
pm2 start --node-args="-r dotenv/config" build/index.js --name API
```

If I try to run the application in cluster mode though, it seems to ignore node-args and fails to load the environment variables.

```
pm2 start --node-args="-r dotenv/config" build/index.js -i max --name API
```

What would be the proper workaround to solve this issue without adding it explicitly to the application code? Should I even be doing it this way to begin with?

**Update:** It appears `pm2 ecosystem` is the correct way to inject command line args if you're looking to run apps in cluster mode. Using `node_args: '-r dotenv/config'` I was able to achieve the desired result. Thanks!

P.S. Make sure you set your environment to production or you may run into unintended issues when launching the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use an ecosystem file for PM2?

Running the following will generate a basic config file.

```
pm2 ecosystem
```

The default file is included below:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'API',
    script: 'app.js',

    // Options reference: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
    args: 'one two',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }],

  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : 'node',
      host : 'localhost',
      ref  : 'origin/master',
      repo : 'git@github.com:repo.git',
      path : '/var/www/production',
      'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production'
    }
  }
};
```

According to the example in the documentation, you can add an "exec_mode" to the json file. See below:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name        : "worker",
    script      : "./worker.js",
    watch       : true,
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    },
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  },{
    name       : "api-app",
    script     : "./api.js",
    instances  : 4,
    exec_mode  : "cluster"
  }]
}
```

Modify the file as needed and run with:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```